# Is it possible to enable bluetooth of another android phone by my android phone

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I want to develop an android app which should  have functionality to enable bluetooth of another android phone.

Answer (score 0):

This will only be possible if you install on both phones an app. At phone 1 you have the app where you can turn on/off bluetooth of the other phone. The app on phone 2 receives this on/off message and turns bluetooth on or off using the Bluetooth permission.

But I think your idea does not make sense since you need to communicate between those two apps that app2 knows to turn on bluetooth. So this communication would only work via internet/wlan.

Without installing an app on phone2 this is not possible due to security reasons.